# adding language filter to twitter popularhashtags - scala

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and Scala. I ran the Spark streaming job-twitter popular hash tags.

I added a filter for some words and was able to filter out tweets :

```
val filter = Array("spark", "Big Data")
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filter)
```

Likewise I want to add a language filter so that only English tweets are streamed. Twitter4j has `Track()` and `Locations`. Does it have a language filter? If so, how does it work in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

I'm repeating what's already been said in [this Spark thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/filtering-out-non-English-tweets-using-TwitterUtils-td18614.html).

Spark uses Twitter4J for the feed. Twitter4J as of version 3.0.6 has `getLang` ([doc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getLang--)) which allows you to:

```
.filter(_.getLang == "en")
```

which can be used against the `DStream` of `twitter4j.Status`.

But unfortunately Spark uses an older [version](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/twitter/pom.xml#L53) of Twitter4J ([doc](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.3/twitter4j/Status.html)) which doesn't have `getLang`.

Either upgrade Twitter4J within Spark to 3.0.6, wait for Spark to upgrade Twitter4J, or an altogether different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am getting the runtime error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.Status.getLang()Ljava/lang/String .I am building the application using sbt. The code is like                val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    val lanFilter = stream.filter(status => status.getLang == "en")
    val hashTags = lanFilter.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))   and in the sbt built file I changed the dependency to libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.6" . Can you tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Looks like 3.0.6 isn't being used by Spark.

Comment: Thank you.Then what is the way out. I am using spark 1.3 and my sbt dependencies are  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.3.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.6" . Any inputs in this regard?