# Spark Streaming - Twitter - Filtering tweet data

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am working on spark streaming with twitter data. I flatmapped the stream into individual words.Now, I need to eliminate tweet words like which start with #,@ and words like RT from streaming data before processing them. I knew it is quite easy to do.I wrote filter for this, but it is not working. Can anyone help on this. My code is

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    //val lanFilter = stream.filter(status => status.getLang == "en")
    val RDD1 = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" "))
    val filterRDD = RDD1.filter(word =>(word !=word.startsWith("#")))
    filterRDD.print()
```

Also language filter is showing error.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could show us the code you wrote, so we can help you better ?

Comment: My code is like this - val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    //val lanFilter = stream.filter(status => status.getLang == "en")
    val RDD1 = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" "))
    val filterRDD = RDD1.filter(word =>(word !=word.startsWith("#")))

Comment: Edit your question and add the code in there. Comments have limited markdown support.

Comment: @SNR Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your lambda expression correct? I think you want:

`val filterRDD = RDD1.filter(word => !word.startsWith("#"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built in word filter support:

```
TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("filter", "these", "words"))
```

But if you want to fix your code:

```
.filterNot(_.getText.startsWith("#"))
```

Regarding language, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014369/adding-language-filter-to-twitter-popularhashtags-scala).

Comment: Thank you.. but the filter in the TwitterUtils deals with set of filter strings to get only those tweets that match them. My need is to remove stop words like - RT,is,has...etc..

Comment: See updated answer, you can use `filterNot` to achieve that. :)