# Error in Spark Streaming code in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming in scala, where I am working with streaming twitter data. I have the following code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Seconds(5))
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

val user = tweets.map(x=> x.getText())
val lang = tweets.map(x=> x.getLang())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[error] /home/user/Lab1.1/Twitterstats.scala:103: value getLang is not a member of twitter4j.Status
[error]                 val lang = tweets.map(x=> x.getLang())
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
```

What is wrong with the above code? Could someone please help.

Comment: what version of spark-streaming-twitter are you using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**spark-streaming-twitter** uses **Twitter4j**. `getLang()` is only supported since version **3.0.6** of **Twitter4J**. If you are using a version **1.5.2** (or lower) of **spark-streaming-twitter** you won't be able to call `getLang()` because it uses version **3.0.3** of **twitter4j**. Since **1.6.0** version **4.0.4** is supported as wel as the `getLang()` function.

So you could upgrade **spark-streaming-twitter** to **1.6.0** or higher. Or you could use another 3rd party library to detect the language of your tweets.

(possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014369/adding-language-filter-to-twitter-popularhashtags-scala))